# Fittext on different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fonts, fittextjs

I'm working with fittext.js. It's working clearly. But my problem is different screen sizes. If I use the 100% width for container on 1920px*1080px font size is bigger than 1280px*800px. But if I define the width for container like 800px 2 screen size has same font size. How can I  change it?

Comment: change what to what? you describe both, but you don't say what you need or what;s not working to your whims...

Comment: I want to if I view it on smaller screen font-size will be small. But it's same all screens in width defined container.

Comment: use css media queries to set a different font-size under different screen sizes...

Comment: I want to use fittext. If I use the the media queries why I'm using fittext?

Comment: well i think you want to use the wrong tool for the job. fittext is for fitting text into containers, font-size is for fitting text into screens... i may want to use a can opener to open a bottle of wine, but a corkscrew would be much easier...

Comment: But if I use the 100% width it's working perfectly. Just I need the defined width settings. Thanks for your comments.